# Android View Binding -> CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Here is the exception I'm getting:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to
>   androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

The problem is, the view being "casted" IS drawer layout.

What am I missing?

[image: Debug]

I added cast for verbosity sake.

[image: Exception]

Here is the drawerLayout in question

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">
```

And drawer

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:menu="@menu/home_drawer" />
```

Comment: That looks to be happening in the `isDrawerOpen()` call, not your own explicit cast, there. That would mean that `binding.drawer` is not a direct child of the `DrawerLayout`, but is inside a `CoordinatorLayout`. Are you sure you have the layout set up correctly? If that `<NavigationView>` is meant to the drawer, it must be directly inside the `<DrawerLayout>`, after everything inside there.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for pointing that out!